# how to get JSON of WIX web site data

Tags: android, json, hybrid-mobile-app, velo

I want to make an Android and iOS app for a site dsstrucks.com 
The thing is i am not able to get the JSON data of the site. Is there a way by which i can get JSON of WIX Site so that i can use it to create an App.

I want a way by which i can get all latest updates also, just like the woocommerce rest api. Or is there a way i can create my own API for this ?

I have tried POST MAN to check GET requests and still no luck. Any minor or major help would be great full.

Thank in Advance

Comment: you should know backend like php to create your own api otherwise look for the sites which provide api

Comment: I know php, but I just don't know how to get the data off the site. I just need a Kickstarter​ thing.

Comment: do you already have a solution for this? Please share. Thanks

Comment: @SakuraFukuyoshi not yet, if you have please share. I would be really thankfull